# How to convert given data into IEnumerable object

Tags: linq, c#-4.0

I have below code in c# 4, where I am trying to use linq for ordering, grouping.

```
IList<Component> components = Component.OrganizationalItem.OrganizationalItem.Components(true);
IEnumerable<Component> baggage = components.Where(x => x.IsBasedOnSchema(Constants.Schemas.BaggageAllowance.ToString()))
                                           .OrderBy(x => x.ComponentValue("name").StringValue("Code")) 
                                           .GroupBy(x => x.ComponentValue("name").StringValue("Code"));
```

In above sample when I am trying to use `GroupBy` it is giving error, please see below:

> Cannot implicitly convert type '`System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Linq.IGrouping<string,Tridion.ContentManager.ContentManagement.Component>>`' to '`System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Tridion.ContentManager.ContentManagement.Component>`'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)*

Comment: "it is giving error" is *never* enough detail. You should always give the compiler error, or exception etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result of `GroupBy` will be an [`IGrouping<string, Component>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/bb344977.aspx) - it's a sequence of *groups* of components, rather than one sequence of components. That's the whole point of grouping. So this should be fine:

```
IEnumerable<IGrouping<string, Component>> baggage = ... query as before ...;
```

Or just use implicit typing:

```
var baggage = ...;
```

You can then iterate over the groups:

```
foreach (var group in baggage)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Key: {0}", group.Key);
    foreach (var component in group)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: after using IGrouping it is giving below error Error 1 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Linq.IGrouping<string,Tridion.ContentManager.ContentManagement.Component>>' to 'System.Linq.IGrouping<string,Tridion.ContentManager.ContentManagement.Component>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Instead if using "var" it is working fine, what chagnes we should if you want to use IGrouping<String, Component>

Comment: Change your `baggage` declaration  to `IEnumerable<IGrouping<string, Component>> baggage`, or use `var` instead: `var baggage = (...)`

Comment: @Jon, thanks for the updates, can you please suggest as we are able to read key with group.Key, now how can I read the key value of that group

Comment: I don't know what you mean - the key value of the group *is* group.Key.

Comment: @Jon, foreach (var group in baggage){} loop giving "Object refernece error", I doubt we are not making correct object for looping can you please look into this

Comment: @ManojSingh: No, I can't look into it with no idea where you're getting the data from, and with that little information. You're the one in the right situation to look into it - you can look at the exact stack trace, check the data, etc.

Comment: @jon, as per your suggestion we got the Igrouping object which contains <String, List<Component>> object then it should be okay for doing the loop still not convinced why it should give the "Object Reference error" any other clue

Comment: @ManojSingh: Yes, there are plenty of clues - but they're all on your side! Look at the stack trace, look at the data, try to isolate the problem... there's nothing I can do with that little information. It's like phoning up a doctor and saying, "I have some spots somewhere on my body. What's wrong, and what medicine should I take?" It's *really* important that you become proficient in diagnosing problems yourself.