# How to check for duplicate property values given a list of objects and return the objects?

Tags: c#

Referring to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/312024/linqy-way-to-check-if-any-objects-in-a-collection-have-the-same-property-value), the original poster needed to find all `agent` objects in a list that had the same `ID` property value.

```
 var duplicates = agents.GroupBy(a => a.ID).Where(a=>a.Count() > 1);

 foreach (var agent in duplicates)
 {
         Console.WriteLine(agent.Key.ToString());
 }
```

The above was the given solution, but I can't figure out how to access the objects in "duplicates". If I do the following:

```
 var duplicates = agents.GroupBy(a => a.ID).Where(a=>a.Count() > 1);

 foreach (var agent in duplicates)
 {
         Console.WriteLine(agent.ID);
         agent.duplicate = true;

 }
```

I get

> 'IGrouping' does not contain a definition for 'ID' and no extension method 'ID' accepting a first argument of type 'IGrouping' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: likely you will find your answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16075683/1132334

Answer (score 0):

As the error clearly says...

> 'IGrouping' does not contain a definition for 'ID' and no extension
>   method 'ID' accepting a first argument of type 'IGrouping' could be
>   found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

You need to return a type that has the properties you want.

```
 var duplicates = agents.GroupBy(a => a.ID).Where(a=>a.Count() > 1).Select(x => new { ID = x.Key});
```

Answer (score 0):

if you just want the duplicated IDs then you can add a Select to the end of the chain.

```
IEnumerable<int> duplicateIds = agents
    .GroupBy(a => a.ID)
    .Where(a => a.Count() > 1)
    .Select(a => a.Key);
```

Comment: I actually want the objects that have the duplicate IDs.

Answer (score 0):

this is how i would do it without group-by :

```
  List<Agent> duplicates = new HashSet<Agent>(agents.Where(c => agents.Count(x => x.ID == c.ID) > 1)).ToList();
```

Answer (score -1):

Couldn't you just set up a list of the objects, loop over the list and remove duplicates once found?

```
 List<agent> Agents = new List<agent>();

    foreach (Agent A in Agents)
    {
        foreach (Agent B in Agents)
        {
            if (A.ID == B.ID)
            {
            Agents.Remove(B)
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I actually don't want to remove them, I want to update a property of these records.